# Mysqldump needed column

Tags: mysql

How to use mysqldump to dump specified column only from specified table in database?

I need something like this

```
mysqldump --skip-lock-tables -q -Q -c -e -h localhost -u username -pPassword DatabaseName TableName Field1 Field5 | gzip > /tmp/dump.sql.gz
```

But I get errors only

Comment: I don't see anything in the docs that suggests this is even possible. syntax is `mysqldump [options] [dbname] [tblname ...]` where `...` simply means you can input multiple table names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using mysqldump it's not possible right now, but you may use `into outfile` utility to get the desired output. In your case the query will look like:

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM DatabaseName.TableName INTO OUTFILE "c:/output.txt" FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

Later on you can use this file to upload in another table called TableName2 with just two columns (ie. col1 and col2) by using following sql:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/output.txt' INTO TABLE TableName2 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```